# How to declare a variable inside a functionnal component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, constants, state

I have a variable "myVar" (NOT A STATE)

```
const myComponent = () => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(true)
  const myVar = false

  return <button onClick={() => {myVar = true} >Click here</button>
```

}

As it is written, when the component is re-rendered, then `myVar` is re-initialized...  I want to have the variable keep its previous value.  How can I get this behavior?

Solutions I found are:

SOLUTION 1 : Initialise the variable outside of the component (but not in the component scope)

```
let myVar = 'initial value';
const myComponent = () => {
  ....
  // myVar is updated sometimes when some functions run
}
```

SOLUTION 2 : declare a component prop (but public)

```
const myComponent = ({myVar = true) => {
  ....
}
```

What is the recommended way to solve this problem?

Comment: This is very abstract. It would help if you expressed the problem in practical terms.

Comment: "This way, it's ok ℹ️, but myVar is global : it is not re-initialized when I come back on this route" — Isn't that the entire point of making it global? So it **isn't** re-initialized?

Comment: @Damien when would you like `myVar` to re-initialize?? I am having a hard time understanding this

Comment: Thank you for your questions. Actually, I want to initialize the variable only when I load the component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React docs suggest to use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to keep an arbitrary mutable value around. So, you could do this:

```js
// set ref
const myValRef = React.useRef(true);

// ...

// update ref
myValRef.current = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use solution #1.

The code

```
let myVar = 'initial value';
const myComponent = () => {
  ....
  // myVar is updated sometimes when some functions run
}
```

will keep the variable `myVar` between renders.

The 2nd solution will not work.  The variable as a prop doesn't maintain the state between renders.